# How can I disable dropdown list's value change caused by ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to come up with a solution that will not allow the user to accidentally make a call to `ajax` when some fields on a form were clicked.

For example, I have a form that has City, State and ZipCode dropdownlist.
When data loads on a screen originally, the fields are populated with a data.
Then, when either city or state or both are changed, there is an ajax call that populates ZipCode dropdown for a particular city/state combination.

But, what happens is user accidentally clicks or tabs to state dropdown or city textbox and tabs away and calls ajax that repopulates ZipCodes dropdown and defaults it to the first one retrieved from database.

How can I either disable `ajax` call when user tabs in or out those fields if there was not intent to change a ZipCode.

This is the function that gets called when user tabs in/out. This function is called on `onbeforedeactivate` event on both City `textbox` and ZipCodes `dropdownlist`:

```
function StateSelected(city, state, ddlZipName)
{
// city is a textbox
// state is a ddl

//  var mySelect = state;


   if ((state.selectedIndex > 0) && (city.value.length > 0))
   {
    //instantiate XmlHttpRequest

        // Checking if IE-specific document.all collection exists 
        // to see if we are running in IE 
        if (document.all) { 
            xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
        } else { 
        // Mozilla - based browser 
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }
        //hook the event handler
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = HandlerOnReadyStateChange;
        //prepare the call, http method=GET, false=asynchronous call
        // alert(state.options[state.selectedIndex].value + 
        // " " + city.value + " " + ddlZipName); 
        xhttp.open("GET", "../sample.ashx?state=" + state.options[state.selectedIndex].value + "&city=" + city.value + "&ddlZipName=" + ddlZipName, false);
        //finally send the call
        xhttp.send();          
   }
 }
```

The `onbeforedeactivate` event generated inside the code:

```
        txtCorporationLegalCity.Attributes.Add("onbeforedeactivate", "StateSelected(document.all['" + txtCorporationLegalCity.ClientID.ToString() + "'], document.all['" + ddlCorporationLegalState.ClientID.ToString() + "'], '" + ddlCorporationLegalZip.ClientID.ToString() + "')");
        ddlCorporationLegalState.Attributes.Add("onbeforedeactivate", "StateSelected(document.all['" + txtCorporationLegalCity.ClientID.ToString() + "'], document.all['" + ddlCorporationLegalState.ClientID.ToString() + "'], '" + ddlCorporationLegalZip.ClientID.ToString() + "')");
```

I can only think of disabling `ajax` call for now. If there are any other solutions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just remember the last arguments of a StateSelected() call, so if get called again with same args, simply do no ajax and keep previous values.